# Raspbian :Automatically mount external drives (plug & play)

Tags: linux, usb, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Shouldn't I be able to plug in a USB device into my raspberry pi and for it to automatically mount? I decided not to use the Desktop Enviornment of Raspbian. When I list the mounts in /mnt I don't see anything mounted? (or /media).

I would like to simply plug a usb or any external device and for it to mount to a folder automatically WITHOUT executing commands like mount or adding the mount to fstab.

Is this possible?

I would think it is seeing if I use a File Manager such as Nautilus in a Desktop Enviornment, that the shares mount automatically.

Comment: Yes? No? Did that help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  All you need to do is to record the UUID of the external device(s) and make a few adjustments to your system.  One way of going about it is nicely described [HERE](http://www.techjawab.com/2013/06/how-to-setup-mount-auto-mount-usb-hard.html)

Replicating the steps here seems pointless as we don't know anything about the number of disks and in what way you plan to use them, or what file-systems are in use.

Comment: Ya that would work. Very similar to using fstab though...

Comment: _All you need to do is to record the UUID_ Oh yeah? Really?  _All you need_  ?? - Come on, would you dare tell this to your mother?? The question is about 'plug and play' and getting complicated hex number each time a new stick is inserted and then making  'a few adjustments to the system' is exactly the opposite.

Comment: @TaW. I didn't **make** Raspbian. I just offered a workaround. Your comment has no value.

Comment: I just pointed out that your answer, although accepted, is factually wrong.

Comment: link is dead so this doesn't answer the question anymore.  Also, you'd need to know the UUID for each USB drive which isn't really plug and play.